# Sorting multiple rows of un-sorted data based on text string - GSheets

Tags: database, google-sheets, formula

I'm working on a data consolidation project and I'm hitting a wall when it comes to sorting data based on cell contents as reference.

I have a dataset of company data (Red Tab) and a list of company names (Blue Tab), both from different sources.

- There are no duplicates in the company name list
- There are some duplicates in the company data list that need to remain as is - ie, Multiple Atlassian entries
- I need to merge the two lists so the company list rows line up with the company data in the Company Name tab
- If there are duplicate company data entries then I need them all pulled into the Company Name sheet

I have a feeling that these requirements will go beyond a formulaic solution and more into macro building, which is fine, but I wanted to test the simpler option first. I've attempted an if statement which half works, but it relies on the data being ordered, see below:

`=arrayformula(if(A2:A='Company Data'!A2:A,'Company Data'!B2:H,""))`

As well as a vlookup formula, which only returns the first entry from the company datasheet:

`=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A,'Company Data'!$A$2:$H,2,FALSE),""))`

The worksheet can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zff-Kry-6vZif94nuekD8l9fHIQvXOkn3k0rvKetSIA/edit#gid=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please briefly explain the desired output with a sample.

Comment: share an example of the desired output

Comment: I have added a tab in the spreadsheet to show the desired output, thanks!